# окно с фоном и полосой прокрутки

Tags: html, css, html5, position, modal

Нужно сделать окно с фиксированным (не двигающимся) фоном (png изображение) и прокручивающимся текстом внутри него (обычный скролл текста вверх вниз).

Так же у окна должна быть кнопка закрытия (png изображение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали? В чём возникло затруднение? Добавьте в вопрос код ваших попыток.

Comment: верное замечание, спасибо. Попытки есть, но это все делалось в проекте. я занялся переносом в repl, но так как ниже человек дал верный ответ, то доделывать не буду, учту на будущее. Но честно говоря толку от моего кода никакого практически)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопку закрытия незачем делать картинкой, можно сверстать

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  $('.popup').addClass('active');
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.popup').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.popup{
  display: none;
}
.popup.active{
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.popup-block{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/dDSjZWs/image.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  padding: 30px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.popup-block-text{
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.popup-block .close{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.popup-block .close:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
.popup-block .close::after{
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Вызвать popup</a>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-block">
    <div class="popup-block-text">
      Не следует, однако, забывать о том, что курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект требует определения и уточнения форм воздействия? Соображения высшего порядка, а также дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности обеспечивает актуальность существующих финансовых и административных условий! Таким образом, реализация намеченного плана развития в значительной степени обуславливает создание всесторонне сбалансированных нововведений.

      Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что выбранный нами инновационный путь способствует подготовке и реализации существующих финансовых и административных условий? Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что новая модель организационной деятельности напрямую зависит от экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений. Задача организации, в особенности же постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации системы обучения кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям? С другой стороны постоянное информационно-техническое обеспечение нашей деятельности играет важную роль в формировании новых предложений.

      Задача организации, в особенности же постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности требует от нас анализа модели развития. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченного плана развития напрямую зависит от дальнейших направлений развитая системы массового участия. Дорогие друзья, постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности способствует повышению актуальности новых предложений! Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что повышение уровня гражданского сознания напрямую зависит от существующих финансовых и административных условий.

      Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянное...
    </div>
    <span class="close"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто) спасибо большое) изображение кнопки закрытия дано по условию, но с вашим примером я думаю заменить будет не сложно (я надеюсь). Извините за вопрос, верстка адаптивная ? чтобы я просто был в курсе. Сейчас пока в плане верстки у меня только чтение mdn, но выдать что то такое для меня пока очень сложно

Comment: Блок выстраивается по центру экрана, так что должен быть адаптивным, но блок 300px ширины, так что при экранах меньше может вылезать, но думаю до таких экранов дойти не должно